# I'm trying to use the max command in pandas and it's returning "'Series' object is not callable", obs.: i'm a newbie

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to learn this command, but i can't do it right, can you suggest something?

```
df['Global_Sales'].max(index(), columns(), skipna=False, level=15, numeric_only=int)
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-25017f1d27cb> in <module>
----> 1 df['Global_Sales'].max(index(), columns(), skipna=False, level=15, numeric_only=int)

TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable~
```

Comment: What are `index` and `columns`? Remove the `()` after them

Comment: If I remove, It says that both index or columns are not defined. Maybe I'm using it wrong? I'm trying to learn the dataframe.max command in pandas/python.

Comment: Look at the [official doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html) and supply only the allowable parameters.  No extra.   Also note for correct use of `level` and `numeric_only` parameters which seems you might have used them incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to display the max value use:

```
print(df['Global_sales'].max(axis=None,skipna=False,level=15,numeric_only=None))
```

If you want to display the index of the max value use:

```
print(df['Global_sales'].idxmax(axis=1,skipna=False)
```

and maybe check pandas.series.max parameters here
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html